# How to get the list of jms queues from Summary of Resources table in weblogic for a certain cluster?

Tags: java, weblogic

```
JMXServiceURL serviceURL = new JMXServiceURL("t3", hostname, port, "/jndi/" + DomainRuntimeServiceMBean.MBEANSERVER_JNDI_NAME);
Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
h.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);
h.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
h.put(JMXConnectorFactory.PROTOCOL_PROVIDER_PACKAGES, "weblogic.management.remote");
MBeanServerConnection bco = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(serviceURL, h).getMBeanServerConnection();

DomainRuntimeServiceMBean domainRuntimeServiceMBean = (DomainRuntimeServiceMBean) MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(bco, new ObjectName(DomainRuntimeServiceMBean.OBJECT_NAME));        
DomainMBean dem = domainRuntimeServiceMBean.getDomainConfiguration();
JMSSystemResourceMBean[] jmsSRs = dem.getJMSSystemResources();

JMSServerMBean[] jmsSvrs = dem.getJMSServers();
for(JMSServerMBean jmsSvr : jmsSvrs){
  System.out.println("JMS Servername: "+jmsSvr.getName());
}

for(JMSSystemResourceMBean jmsSR : jmsSRs){
  System.err.println(jmsSR.getName());
  QueueBean[] qbeans = jmsSR.getJMSResource().getQueues();
    for(QueueBean qbean : qbeans){
      System.out.println("JNDI NAME: "+qbean.getJNDIName()+" queuename : "+qbean.getName());
    }
}
```

I use this code to get all queues from weblogic and it works. But now I need to get queues of a certain cluster. I have two of them and each of them has a listening port. But putting the port in this code above does not work. How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each JMS Server, you can check to see what it is *targeted to* and then only print out the queues for it. Something like:

```
JMSServerMBean[] jmsSvrs = dem.getJMSServers();

for(JMSServerMBean jmsSvr : jmsSvrs){
   System.out.println("JMS Servername: "+jmsSvr.getName());

   TargetMBean[] targets = jmsSvr.getTargets()
   for(TargetMBean target : targets)
   {
      if ( target.getName() == "cluster you care about")
      {
          JMSQueueMBean[] queues = jmsSvr.getJMSQueues();
          ...
      }
   }
 }
```

You can look up all of the available API call in the [docs here](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WLAPI/toc.htm), so you can explore a little before asking another question.